# Poles of formal power series (Hilbert-Poincaré series)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, dimension-theory-analysis

How are poles and orders of poles of formal power series defined?

The particular case, I am interested in, is the following definition from [Atiyah-Macdonald, Introduction to commutative algebra, p.116]:

Let $A$ be a graded Ring, $M$ a finitely generated graded $A$-module and $\lambda$ an additive function on the class of finitely generated $A_0$-modules (e.g. the length-function). Then the Hilbert-Poincaré series $P(M,t) \in \mathbb{Z}[[t]]$ is defined as
$$ P(M,t) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda(M_n) t^n. $$
Now $d(M)$ is defined to be the order of the pole of $P(M,t)$ at $t=1$. What exactly is $d(M)$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you asking what a pole of a rational function means? Or did you miss that $P$ is a rational function? (Theorem 11.1)

Comment: If $\rm\: P(t) = f(t)/((t-1)^n g(t)),\ f(1),g(1)\ne 0\:$ then $\rm\,P\,$ has a pole of order $\rm\:n\:$ at $\rm\:t = 1.\:$ Here we know that the power series is that of a rational function, so it makes sense to speak of poles. Otherwise it would not. [reply to a comment now deleted]

Comment: @MathGems: Thank you! This is actually an answer, not a comment :) So poles are just defined for those formal power series, which are rational functions?

Comment: Generally it doesn't make sense to speak of the pole at $\rm\:t = 1\:$ of a formal power series $\rm\:P(t)\:$ since $\rm\:P(t)\:$ cannot even be evaluated at $\rm\:t = 1\:$ without some notion of convergence, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Theorem 11.1, we know that $\rm\:P(M,t)\:$ is a *rational function*. Recall their notion of pole: if $\rm\: P(t) = f(t)/((t-1)^n g(t)),\:$ with $\rm\: f(1),g(1)\ne 0\:$ then $\rm\,P\,$ has a pole of order $\rm\:n\:$ at $\rm\:t = 1.\:$